# Convert image to Base64 in Orchard CMS

Tags: image, orchardcms

When I call the Orchard service to return the HTML content of a page, the HTML contains a URL of the image. Is there a way for the service to return the image as Base64?

I hope you can help me.

Comment: I don't use Orchard CMS but... I doubt a CMS service would do extract & convert. What programming language are you using? Maybe write a function to read image bytes (numbers) from url & then convert the numbers to base64 equivalent, this way you have converted it base64.

Comment: Which service do you mean?